# SSLSessionContextImpl Error (null pointer) in JAX-WS generated code?

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, jax-ws

Can anyone tell me if this is related to the SSL session, or if this is indicative of a certificate issue?

I'm using some code created from JAX `wsimport` and have run into an occassional issue.  The error thrown seems to be related to SSL session invalidation.  However, this code was working fine previously and I am at a loss as to where to look.

Exception:

```
 [ java.lang.NullPointerException ] java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionContextImpl.remove(SSLSessionContextImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.invalidate(SSLSessionImpl.java:558)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1559)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1547)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1511)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1456)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:64)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at java.io.PrintStream.flush(PrintStream.java:286)
    at sun.net.www.MessageHeader.print(MessageHeader.java:228)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.writeRequests(HttpClient.java:602)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:430)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:970)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1007)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.createReader(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:837)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.resolveWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:294)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:151)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:131)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:267)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:230)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:106)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57)
... (truncated)
```

**EDIT:**

I traced the exception up through the stacktrace and found myself at the line `com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:64)`.  This appears to be writing bytes to the output stream, and catches any exceptions thrown during this process.  Within the catch block, it sends the exception into the `SSLSocketImpl` class which eventually tries to invalidate the session.  During the session invalidation is where the null pointer occurs (a secondary exception).

AppOutputStream.write():

```
public synchronized void write(byte[] paramArrayOfByte, int paramInt1, int paramInt2)
throws IOException
{
    this.c.checkWrite();
    try
    {
      do
      {
        int i = Math.min(paramInt2, this.r.availableDataBytes());

        if (i > 0) {
          this.r.write(paramArrayOfByte, paramInt1, i);
          paramInt1 += i;
          paramInt2 -= i;
        }
        this.c.writeRecord(this.r);
        this.c.checkWrite();
      }while (paramInt2 > 0);
    }
    catch (Exception localException) {
      this.c.handleException(localException);
    }
}
```

The details of the initial exception are not printed by default.  You must use the jvm switch `-Djavax.net.debug=SSL,session` to get this information to print to your localhost/console log.  I have enabled this in my test environment, but have never seen the error there so it may not prove useful.  Because of the volume of logging information this produces, I am wary of enabling this option in production.

It seems that the literal question I asked may be answered with these findings.  However, the source of the exception (the output stream writes occasionally failing) is still unanswered.

Request suggestions about closing/answering this question and opening another, or continuing to solicit responses here.

Comment: Does the webserver require client auth??

Comment: In this case the client is Tomcat and the server is IIS with WIA enabled.  However, client and server are on the same VM, and this code works most of the time.  The error occurs only sporadically.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't really answer your question directly.  The answer is no.